# Why I use PDO to insert non-english char will become monster?

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, pdo, phpmyadmin

This is what I do in php:

```
$dbhandler = new PDO('mysql:host='.domain.':'.port.';dbname='.dbName.';',db_user,db_password);        

$stmt = $dbhandler->prepare("INSERT INTO ".myTable.
" (value) VALUES (:value)");
$stmt->bindValue(':value', "試打中文");

$stmt->execute();
```

This is what I get via phpMyAdmin:

```
è©¦æ‰“ä¸­æ–‡
```

But I can manually insert chinese in phpMyAdmin, and it shows to monster char...
What did I do wrong? (The Collation of table field is : utf8_unicode_ci).

Thank you.

Comment: So you're assuming that PHPMyAdmin is showing inserted data correctly, using appropriate charset? I'm afraid you're wrong and that you should ditch PHPMyAdmin forever.. it's one of the worst things ever made to handle MySQL. Basically, you did nothing wrong. If you output the record to your web page using correct encoding (utf8), you should see that "monster char" as you called it just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$dbhandler = new PDO('mysql:host='.domain.':'.port.';dbname='.dbName.';',db_user,db_password, array(
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
));
```

Comment: coool, it work, but what is this MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND about?

Comment: From the [pdo manual](http://php.net/manual/ref.pdo-mysql.php): *Command to execute when connecting to the MySQL server. Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.

Note, this constant can only be used in the driver_options array when constructing a new database handle.* And from mysql about [SET NAMES utf8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try also running:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;
```

As queries after you make the database connection.